# loop if statement works until you switch tabs. Very odd issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using ajax to turn a mysql query into a json output file and I have a function to loop through the json data and append html for items matching criteria. I have 3 jquery tabs, Season 1, Season B, and All Cards.

When I first load the page it defaults to Season 1 tab and all the html for the data matching Season 1 displays just fine. If I switch to Season B tab everything loads. But then when I switch back to Season 1 nothing loads. Also clicking All Cards nothing loads.

I added console output and I can see that everything matches the criteria. For example the if statements is looking for tabContainer="1" aka Season and cardSet="Base" aka Set. And the console output literally says Base 1 Didn't match Base 1 meaning that it DOES match but for whatever reason it is skipping the if statement entirely and heading straight to else.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    var data;


    function clearCardImages(tabContainer) {
        $("#cardslist-s" + tabContainer).empty();
        console.log("Clearing card data from #cardslist-s" + tabContainer);
    }

    function loadAndDisplayData(cardSetTerm, tabContainer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "get_card_data.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (jsonData) {
                data = jsonData;
                console.log("Data contents: ", data);
                console.log("The current selection is Season " + tabContainer + " " + cardSetTerm + " set.");
                    $.each(data, function (index, card) {
                        var cardImage = card.card_image;
                        var cardSet = card.card_set;
                        var rarity = card.rarity;
                        var season = card.season;
                        var setNumber = card.set_number;
                        var cardCn = card.card_cn;
                        var pocketfurCn = card.pocketfur_cn;
                        console.log("Card Set:", cardSet, "Season:", season);

                        if (cardSet === cardSetTerm && season === tabContainer) {
                            console.log(cardSetTerm + " " + tabContainer + " matched", cardSet, season);
                            $("#cardslist-s" + tabContainer).append("<a href='../../../pfmedia/cards/" + cardImage + "' target='_blank' data-cardset='" + cardSet + "'>" +
                                "<img id='cardimg' src='../../../pfmedia/cards/s" + season + "/" + cardSet + "/" + cardCn + "-thumb.gif' alt='' title='Season " + season + " ◽️ " + rarity + " ◽️ " + cardSet + " ◽️ " + pocketfurCn + "' />" +
                                "</a>");
                        }
                        else if (cardSet === "all" && season === "all") {
                            console.log("Creating All Card images.");
                            $("#cardslist-sall").append("<a href='../../../pfmedia/cards/" + cardImage + "' target='_blank' data-cardset='" + cardSet + "'>" +
                                "<img id='cardimg' src='../../../pfmedia/cards/s" + season + "/" + cardSet + "/" + cardCn + "-thumb.gif' alt='' title='Season " + season + " ◽️ " + rarity + " ◽️ " + cardSet + " ◽️ " + pocketfurCn + "' />" +
                                "</a>");
                        }
                        else  {
                            console.log(cardSetTerm + " " + tabContainer + " didn't match", cardSet, season);
                        }
                    });
    
            }
        });
    }

    $(".filter-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cardSetTerm = $(this).data("cardset");
        var tabContainer = getActiveTab();
        console.log("Filtering cards by Season " + tabContainer + " " + cardSetTerm + " set");

        clearCardImages(tabContainer);
        loadAndDisplayData(cardSetTerm, tabContainer);
    }); 

    $(".tabsnav").click(function () {
        var tabContainer = $(this).data("tab");

        console.log("Switching to tab: " + tabContainer);
        console.log("Data contents: ", data);

        clearCardImages(tabContainer);

        if (tabContainer === "all") {
            console.log("Loading " + tabContainer + " cards...");
            loadAndDisplayData("all", tabContainer);
        } 
        else {
            console.log("Loading Season " + tabContainer + " Base Set cards...");
            loadAndDisplayData("Base", tabContainer);
        }

    });

    function getActiveTab() {
        return $('#tabs .ui-tabs-active a').data("tab");
}
    
    loadAndDisplayData("Base", "1");
});
```

Added console output to determine any issues  and here is the result

When loading page initially it stops at the if statement because the terms match

```
Data contents:  (222) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
115 The current selection is Season 1 Base set.
...
127 Base 1 matched Base 1
124 Card Set: Base Season: 1
127 Base 1 matched Base 1
124 Card Set: Base Season: 1
127 Base 1 matched Base 1
...
```

Then switching to second tab it also stops at the if statement because matches

```
Switching to tab: b
163 Data contents:  (222) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
99 Clearing card data from #cardslist-sb
172 Loading Season b Base Set cards...
114 Data contents:  (222) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
115 The current selection is Season b Base set.
...
127 Base b matched Base b
124 Card Set: Base Season: b
127 Base b matched Base b
124 Card Set: Base Season: b
127 Base b matched Base b
...
```

Then switching back it skips if and goes to the else statement because it doesn't match but the output shows it matches still

```
Switching to tab: 1
163 Data contents:  (222) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
99 Clearing card data from #cardslist-s1
172 Loading Season 1 Base Set cards...
114 Data contents:  (222) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
115 The current selection is Season 1 Base set.

...
124 Card Set: Base Season: 1
139 Base 1 Didn't match Base 1
124 Card Set: Base Season: 1
...
```

And finally switching to the All tab it skips the if else statement and skips to the else statement even though it meets the criteria

```
Switching to tab: all
163 Data contents:  (222) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
99 Clearing card data from #cardslist-sall
168 Loading all cards...
114 Data contents:  (222) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
115 The current selection is Season all all set.
124 Card Set: Cosmic Season: b
139 all all Didn't match Cosmic b
124 Card Set: Cosmic Season: b
139 all all Didn't match Cosmic b
124 Card Set: Cosmic Season: b
139 all all Didn't match Cosmic b
124 Card Set: Cosmic Season: b
139 all all Didn't match Cosmic b
124 Card Set: Cosmic Season: b
139 all all Didn't match Cosmic b
...
```

I've already tested this running cloudflare in dev mode so there is no cache issue

Comment: If elements are being added to the DOM dynamically (which seems to be the case with your tabs), the click events might not be firing as expected because they don't exist when the page loads. You might need to use event delegation to handle these cases, attaching an event to a static element and listening for events there.

Comment: I updated my script to use delegation against the #tabs div but it still doesn't work. This is a little foreign to me, is this pretty much what you meant?

    $("#tabs").on("click", ".tabsnav", function () {
        var tabContainer = $(this).data("tab");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after much trial and error. It was because the click function for the tab was pulling a custom attribute as an integer

Had to convert it to a string

```
$("#tabs").on("click", ".tabsnav", function() {
    var tabContainer = $(this).data("tab").toString();
```